# How to execute a very long function in php

Tags: php, timeout, photo

I need to get 3000+ photos from a remote server to my server... each photo take about .25 sec to read/write. So to get 3000+ photos will take about 13 minutes now.

Having a PHP file executing a function for this long get a fail result... i got about 500 files, and then I see an error (wordpress 404 not found).

**The question is, how to get it to work ?**

On the final script, i will need to get more than 10 000 pictures... now it's just a test to see if it can be done..

here is the code that make it work :

```
file_put_contents($complete_photo_name, file_get_contents($photo['PhotoURL']));
```

thanks in advance

NOTE : I paid to get access to those pictures, it's completely legit and must be done this way, the company don't want hot linking ! and ask me to donwload it. Instead of checking each picture when i need it, and downloding it, i need to download them all, and never have to check/download it again for the day/week/year

Comment: Split them up and call the function with chunks of 10 or 20 ? Then you also can react faster if something fails?! (Won't ask now why you want to get 10k images from a remote server...) Also show us your function so we are able to see the potential where you can optimize it

Comment: one hopes he has permission

Comment: NOTE : I paid to get access to those pictures, it's completely legit and must be done this way, the company don't want hot linking ! and ask me to donwload it. Instead of checking each picture when i need it, and downloding it, i need to download them all, and never have to check/download it again for the day/week/year

Comment: for a one off job command line ftp is probably going to be fastest\easiest

Comment: Windows or Linux? Do you have some archiving/compression extensions installed?

Comment: linux, and no compression extension whatsoever, it's php file_put_contents($complete_photo_name, file_get_contents($photo['PhotoURL']));

Comment: Frankly it is silly that you have to go and download each file one by one when all they have to do on their end is compress the entire 10,000 files into one TAR/ZIP file for you to FTP to yourself.